# Update Price Based On Current Filter

Tags: attributes, price, filter, plugin

I've been searching all over, and I can't believe no one has already made a plugin that does this.

So standard Magento, you will filter products, say all size 10's - it will show you all the variable products that have size 10 available - but the price states "From" price....

Now the size 10 is an extra 5 pound than everything else, so is there a way to just show the size 10 price instead of the "From" price? There must be a plugin available for this type of situation?

Comment: Did you find an extension for that?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need something like [this](http://www.best4mage.com/configurable-products-use-simple-price.html) however I have never used this extension nor have I used any extensions from the vendor so I can't say 100% it will work

Comment: Doesn't look like that one does what I'm after, as it still shows "Price From" on the main catalog page, even when filters are set.